# Elegant and efficient way to catch events in items inside list view items in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Supose I have a `ListView`. That `ListView` has items. That items has subitems (for instance, buttons).

I use a subclass of an adaptor for this purpose, so `getView()` is implemented inside the `Adaptor`. I would like to receive the click events of that subitems in some method in my activity in which the `ListView` is. Hope my problem is well explained.

Which is the best approach?

Comment: Instead of having a `ListView` with items that each have buttons, I would recommend that you use a [conditional action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB). Basically, every time you tap an item in the `ListView`, a special action bar appears that can be customized for each item or whatever you want. The reason I am recommending this is because sometimes custom `ListView`s that have buttons and things like that can get cluttered and this is in my experience a more elegant solution visually and it enables you to more easily avoid sloppy code.

Comment: Scott, thank you for your comment. It will be really useful since I didn't know about that!

Comment: no problem! I didnt know about the conditional action bar either when I tried something similar to what you are doing, and it really was a life saver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Which is the best approach?

I don't think there's a *best approach*. One easy and clean way of implementing what you want is to implement a generic listener for the sub items events and pass those through an interface(implemented by your `Activity`):

```
public interface OnButtonEventListener {

    void onSubButtonClicked(int parentRowPosition);
}
```

Your activity will implement this interface.

Then in the adapter build a generic listener:

```
private OnButtonEventListener mBtnListener; // as you'll pass a Context to your adapter, the Activity which implements the OnButtonEventListener
private void OnClickListener mListener = new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          Integer rowPosition = (Integer)  v.getTag();// you could pass other data as well
          mBtnListener.onButtonClicked(rowPosition);
      }

}
```

then in the getView method of the adapter:

```
//...
Button b = ...find the Button
b.setTag(Integer.valueOf(position));
b.setOnClickListener(mListener);
//
```

With this approach is also easy to add event broadcasting to the activity for other sub items if you decide to do so later.